# Links won't work in the Send To location

Tags: 2013

I'm trying to put a link into the **Send To location** but it says the link is too long. Is there anyway to get around this? I've tried to shorten the link, and when I test the link it works, but when I update copies using the managing copies function, the link doesn't work anymore, and it says it failed to send copies.

I think my problem is that when I shorten the link there is a "%20" for the spaces but after I enter and click ok, the %20 disappears and the link doesn't work anymore.

A solution to either problem would be great so I could use the update copies function, thanks!